# how to update json file from azure function in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, json, azure-functions

I can able to read JSON file from azure function and I'm also looking to update the JSON file,
Here code that I have tried.

```
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    var axios = require('axios')
    var path = require('path')
    var fs = require('fs')
    var update_json = require('json-update')
    var response = await axios.get('https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/nifty500StockWatch.json')
    await update_json.update('D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger2\holiday.json',{'name':"jeeva"})
    var data2 = await update_json.load('D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger2\holiday.json') 
    context.log(data2.name)
    context.log(typeof JSON.stringify(response['data']['data']))
    context.log(typeof response['data']['data'])
    return response['data']['data'] 

};
```

Here is my json file.

```
{
    "name":"saran"
}
```

here I'm using the json-update package I'm also ok with some other package, how can I do it?

Comment: Hi Saran, may I know if the solution I provided helps your problem ? If it helps, could you please mark my answer as "accepted" ? Thanks. If still have any other concern about this ticket, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "edit-json-file" package to update json, I post my code below for your reference:

[image]

For further information about "edit-json-file", you can refer to [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/edit-json-file) page.